# How can I call a public void from my PolygonContainer?

Tags: c#, xna

I always get this error message in the following line:

```
  Casttoenum(this.Polygontype);
```

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type
>   'WindowsPhoneGame2.Containerclass' via nested type
>   'WindowsPhoneGame2.Containerclass.PolygonContainer

What is wrong? How can I call the public void Casttoenum from my PolygonContainer?

What is the best way to solve this problem?

```
    public List<PolygonContainer> PolygonList = new List<PolygonContainer>();
    public struct PolygonContainer
    {
        public float PolygonpositionX;
        public float PolygonpositionY;
        public float Polygonrotation;
        public int Polygontype;

        public PolygonContainer(float polygonpositionx, float polygonpositiony, float polygonrotation, int polygontype)
            : this()
        {
            this.PolygonpositionX = polygonpositionx;
            this.PolygonpositionY = polygonpositiony;
            this.Polygonrotation = polygonrotation;
            this.Polygontype = polygontype;
            Casttoenum(this.Polygontype);
        }
    }

    public enum Polygontypes
    {
        PolyState1 = 1,
        PolyState2 = 2,
        PolyState3 = 3
    }

    private Polygontypes currentPolygontype;

    public void Casttoenum(int state)
    {
       currentPolygontype = (Polygontypes)state;                                     
       WhichPolygon(currentPolygontype);
    }

    public List<Vertices> Polyglist = new List<Vertices>();

    public void WhichPolygon(Polygontypes polyliststate)
    {
        switch (polyliststate)
        {
            case Polygontypes.PolyState1:
                Polyglist = list1;
                break;
            case Polygontypes.PolyState2:
                Polyglist = list2;
                break;
            case Polygontypes.PolyState3:
            Polyglist = list3;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the method declaration instead of taking int take Polygontypes (enum) directly , so you can avoid casting.

change PolygonContainer() as below:

```
public PolygonContainer(float polygonpositionx, float polygonpositiony, float polygonrotation, Polygontypes polygontype)
```

then remove the following statements used to cast to enum:

```
this.Polygontype = polygontype; 
Casttoenum(this.Polygontype);
```

while calling PolygonContainer() function one has to pass enum value as last parameter insted of int so that invalid values can not be passed.

Comment: It's not working because the last parameter is an int that I read from a text file.Is there another way to solve the problem?